# How to reassign the address of a named range in Open Office VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, openoffice-calc

In Excel VBA, I redefine the address of a named range with:

```
Ranges("MyRange").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Name = "MyRange"
```

in the Worksheet_Deactivate event.

This way, after updating the spreadsheet, MyDataRange always references to the entire data.
Ok with Excel, but when I tried to migrate this to Open Office VBA (OpenOffice.org 3.1.1 / 
OOO310m19 Build:9420) the ".Name" property of the Range isn't defined.

Then, I tried with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("MyDataRange").RefersTo = Range("MyDataRange").Cells(1).CurrentRegion
```

with no luck ("the property is Read Only" error)

Again, I tried with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add ("MyDataRange", Range("MyDataRange").Cells(1).CurrentRegion)
```

This works, but after that all the cells with validations that references to the named range loses the original reference and shows "#NAME#" in the popup.

Is there any way to reassign the address of a named range without losing the references to it?

TIA,

Pablo

Comment: Whatever you figure out, you have my sympathies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651901/what-do-i-need-to-do-in-order-to-get-openoffice-org-calc-to-read-the-vba-code-in

Comment: I'm not very OO savy, but I wonder if this technique would work? http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm

Comment: @OOrang: that works fine for this specific problem, thanks

Comment: I moved it on down to an answer since it worked:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm) technique would work?